# Why should you get to ...?

Tags: phrase-usage

Scenario:
Two people are in <strike>trouble</strike> conflict with each other. One day, one of them says,

"It's time (for us to stop this.)"

And the other says,

> Why should you **get to** choose when to call time on the conflict between us?

Here, if I omit "get to", will the meaning change or the sentence become unnatural?

Comment: @CowperKettle, thank you, I just want the exact meaning of "get to" here.

Comment: The idiomatic usage *to **get to** [do something]* strongly implies a ***positive achievement / lucky accident***. Including it in the cited context amplifies the implication that  *someone* will "win" the desirable state of being able to make the relevant choice (and speaker is effectively complaining that he has as much right to do that as the other person). If it's *not* included, that same meaning might apply, but in that case the speaker might simply be asking a simple literal question with no implication of *Maybe it should be **me** who chooses, not you*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider these two examples...

> 1: *I never choose a starter in my local restaurant. I always have the "soup of the day"*
>    2: *I never **get to** choose a starter in my local restaurant. I always have the "soup of the day"*

The *context* of #1 strongly implies that I ***could*** choose some other starter dish from the menu - I just don't want to exercise my right to make a choice.

But #2 strongly implies ***I don't have a choice***. Feasibly the restaurant doesn't offer a choice of starter, but more likely it's because I only go to the restaurant with my wife, say, and she always insists on making that choice for me. Whatever the reason though, the strong implication is that *I **would like** to be able to choose for myself, **but I can't***.

---

In general, ***to get to*** [do X] implies that doing (or having the opportunity to do) ***X*** is ***desirable***. Which is *usually* the case with something like "choosing / having a choice" - but as my example above shows, there can be contexts where someone ***doesn't care*** whether or not they have a choice. In which case they wouldn't refer to the situation in terms of ***getting to*** choose.

---

In OP's cited context, including ***get to*** unambiguously conveys that the speaker would like to have a choice. He's effectively saying *Why shouldn't **I** choose, rather than you?* If it's not included, that implication could still be contextually relevant, but feasibly the speaker isn't thinking that ***he*** should have the choice.